# OPC Client as service

Tags: service, dcom, opc

I want to subscribe a TAG value from opc server with OpcGroup_DataChanged event. I am able to do it through a windows form client without any issue. But when I am trying to do the same from windows service, the event is not firing. Can some body Help me? 
I've already modified the DCOM configuration according to:
http://xlreporter.net/download/OPC_and_DCOM.pdf
but the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your service application process Windows messages in the thread that you have initialised the client.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that? Now I'm using opc classic by opc labs.

Comment: I don't recall how that's done in .NET. In Delphi you just call Application.ProcessMessages. I suggest you contact OPC Labs about the recommended way to do that with their library.

Comment: I've seen that the instruction in C# is Application.DoEvents() but usually it's executed in forms instead of multithreading. To be honest I don't understand the reason why the event are not executed in a windows service. My hypothesis was that the OPC Server (on the same machine of the client) is not able to notify the value change to the client.